# jQuery - Sticky header and animated logo when scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I've have a div with id="header" with another div id="logo" ("position:absolute") the inside of which is higher than the header div is.

When scrolling down the page I want to stick the header to the top of the window (which works with no problem) **AND** slide the logo to top `-125px` so that only a small part of the logo is visible.

Sliding up when scrolling down causes no error, but when I scroll back to the top I have a big delay sliding the `#logo` back to its original positon.

Here is my code:

jQuery:

```
var top = jQuery('#header').offset().top;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
     if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > top) {
        jQuery('#header').addClass('header_fixed');
        jQuery('#content').addClass('content_fixed');           
    } else {
        jQuery('#header').removeClass('header_fixed');                  
        jQuery('#content').removeClass('content_fixed');
    }
    if(jQuery('#header').hasClass('header_fixed')) {
        jQuery('#logo').animate({top:'-125px'}, 500);
    } else {
        jQuery('#logo').animate({top:'0px'}, 500);
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To fast the returned scroll try this:

```
var scroll = 0;
var scrolled = false;

jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {
     if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() > scroll){
         if(scrolled == false){
            jQuery('#logo').animate({top:'-125px'}, 500);
            scroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
         }       
        scrolled = true;
    } else {
        if(scrolled == true){
            jQuery('#logo').animate({top: 0}, 500);
            scroll = 0;
        }       
        scrolled = false;            
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if is what you want, this is an example [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/a6nby/3/)

Comment: Worked great! Just used your code to put an animation on a fixed header when user scroll the page.